# Reference not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reference

I am having a problem with my algorithm in javascript. Basically, I am building a graph and I need to keep reference on subgraph. The problem is that from one iteration to other, I loose this reference and I still unable to understand while this behavior. This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
 const SIZE = 1000;

var graph = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [ ]
}

  
var testjson = {
    "angular-chart.js@1.0.3": {
        "chart.js@2.3.0": {
            "chartjs-color@2.0.0": {
                "chartjs-color-string@0.4.0": {
                    "color-name@1.1.1": {}
                },
                "color-convert@0.5.3": {}
            },
            "moment@2.15.2": {}
        },
        "angular@1.5.8": {}
    }
};




function traverse_it(obj, myFunc){
  var  ref = graph;// .children;
  for(var prop in obj){
    
    if( !Object.keys(obj[prop]).length){
      console.log("{}");
      ref.push({'name': prop, 'size': SIZE });
      return;
    }
    else if(typeof obj[prop]==='object'){
      console.log("------------------------------");
      
      console.log(typeof ref);
      console.log('ref in the ginning of iteration');
      console.log(ref);

      ref = ref.children;
      console.log(ref);
      
      ref.push({'name': prop, 'children': [] });
      console.log(ref);
      ref = ref[ref.length -1];
      console.log("--------graph----------------");
      console.log(graph);
      console.log("---------graph----------------");
      console.log('ref at the end of iteration');
      console.log(ref);
      console.log("------------------------------");
      
      if (graph.children.length > 1)
        return;
      traverse_it(obj[prop]);
    }else{
      console.log("error ");
      throw err;
    }
  }
  return;
  
}
traverse_it(testjson);
  

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output is something like this:

```
------------------------------
object
ref in the ginning of iteration
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": []
}
[]
[
  {
    "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
    "children": []
  }
]
--------graph----------------
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
---------graph----------------
ref at the end of iteration
{
  "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
  "children": []
}
------------------------------
------------------------------
object
ref in the ginning of iteration
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
[
  {
    "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
    "children": []
  }
]
[
  {
    "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "chart.js@2.3.0",
    "children": []
  }
]
--------graph----------------
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "angular-chart.js@1.0.3",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "chart.js@2.3.0",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
---------graph----------------
ref at the end of iteration
{
  "name": "chart.js@2.3.0",
  "children": []
}
------------------------------
```

As you can see in this output, ref is changing from iteration 1 to 2. How can I keep the same value of ref (subgraph) at the end of iteration and begin of new iteration.